# "Angular cdk Drag drop" for drag items from list and drop to container (unordered)

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, drag, angular-cdk

I know cdk Drag drop works well with lists and there are lot of examples.

But what I want to do is,

List on one side and container on other side.
Items in the container should be anywhere in the container and that can be holded by x and y axis.

So when dragged from list and dropped at some (x,y) in container, the item should hold that position.

Please help me in this.
Provide code example if possible.

Comment: "Provide code example if possible." how about you provide a stackblitz ppl can use and work on.

Comment: I'm not seeing this as a possibility that seems built into the cdk.  @user9268852 If you found a solution or other direction, please make it known.  I need the same exact solution! 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881107/drag-and-drop-custom-behavior/59882368#59882368 (NOTE: see also the comments-, I put in copy to @Jordan

Comment: a more complex example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916765/drag-and-drop-in-angular-on-complex-board-matrix/59927777#59927777