# Drag and drop custom behavior

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, copy, angular8

I try to implement this behavior http://jsfiddle.net/Aneeshmohan/qbxfbmtt/ 
   in angular 8. I use angular cdk drag-drop module https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ppaey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts but I have some problems:

```
$('.dragger').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: function () {
        //Code here
        return $("<div class='dragger'></div>").append("Hi");
    }
});


$(".dropper").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {

        $(this)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("p")
            .html("Dropped!");

        var element = $('.ui-draggable-dragging');
        var currentDrop=$(this);
        return element.clone().appendTo(currentDrop);
    }
});
```

1.I want to drop the element in a certain position, but instead of that, the element is placed in the top left corner.

2.Currently when dragging the text, the text will get removed (visually) from the source.I want an option to allow the item to stay visible in the source even when appearing in the target.

How to get the desired behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Razvan, I know the cdkDrag is talking always about List, but you needn't use a list. if our "items" has as properties top and left, we can draw in his position.

You can have a drop zone like

```
<div #dropZone class="dropZone" cdkDropList id="drop-list" 
       (cdkDropListDropped)="itemDropped($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let field of fields;" cdkDrag
           style="position:absolute;z-index:10" 
           [style.top]="field.top" 
           [style.left]="field.left">
           {{field.text}}
     </div>
</div>
```

And a list

```
   <div id="div1" cdkDrag cdkDropList 
        cdkDropListConnectedTo="drop-list" 
        *ngFor="let type of types"
        [cdkDragData]="type" (cdkDragMoved)="moved($event)">
        {{type.text}}
        <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="field-placeholder"></div>

    </div>
```

In move we store the position of the pointer

```
  moved(event: CdkDragMove) {
    this._pointerPosition=event.pointerPosition;
  }
```

In dropped calculate the position

```
  itemDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(this.fields, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      event.item.data.top=(this._pointerPosition.y-this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top)+'px'
      event.item.data.left=(this._pointerPosition.x-this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left)+'px'
      this.addField({...event.item.data}, event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
```

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vdmdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts)

For "don't desapear" I think that the only way is make a "fixed copy" behind the drag zone, some like [this another answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685316/how-to-use-angulars-drag-and-drop-module-to-drag-an-element-onto-another/59698494#59698494)

Comment: I found the following problem: you can drop an item outside the box in the right [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vdmdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts) . How can I fix this?

Comment: Razvan ther'e a similar question about drag in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970847/angular-cdk-drag-drop-absolutely-position-elements-without-jumping/59971728#59971728. You can check before add the item if is inside the "drop zone" like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4k1cde4k1cd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The second link doesn't work, can you provide me one that works. Even in this [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970847/angular-cdk-drag-drop-absolutely-position-elements-without-jumping/59971728#59971728) you cand drop the item outside the box in right side.

Comment: sorry, this is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4k1cd