# Angular CDK Drag Drop Absolutely Position Elements Without Jumping

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I'm trying to use the Angular Drag/Drop from the CDK to implement a basic sidebar with draggable elements where the user can drop them anywhere in the "content" area. Meaning, the elements should ultimately be absolutely positioned and should be able to live wherever the user wants them, including on top of each other.

I'm trying to use cdkDropListConnectedTo with a cdkDropList. I have it mostly working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13hhqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), but you can see that when dragging multiple items onto the content area, the previous items jump around. I want the user to be able to drag and drop as many items on the content area as they want, and they should be able to be dropped wherever they please without affecting the other elements.

It seems like some simple CSS would be able to fix this, but now I'm wondering if this is not the right way to go about making this happen.

[image: angular cdk drag drop]

**Updated gif after adding cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"**

[image: angular cdk drag drop]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just include `cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"` in your cdkDropList #dropZone

```
  <div 
      id="page-0" 
      class="document-page dropZone"
      #dropZone 
      cdkDropList 
      id="drop-list"
      cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"   //<----HERE
      (cdkDropListDropped)="itemDropped($event)"
    >
```

**Update** In drop try:

```
itemDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
     const rect=event.item.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
      event.item.data.top=(rect.top+event.distance.y-this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top)+'px'
      event.item.data.left=(rect.left+event.distance.x-this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left)+'px'
      this.addField({...event.item.data}, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo - That did seem to help a bit, but when you drop an element, it still seems to be respecting other elements position in the DOM. I updated the original post with another gif showing the issue (as well as the Stackblitz based on your comment). Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: making trying I think that  I get the solution, see the updated anwer (sorry, I'm in hurry to check)

Comment: That was exactly it. Looks like I had my calculations wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @randyjensen would you mind sharing again the stackblitz link? the link is now broken. It would be nice if you provide the link because I have the same requirement as yours and maybe it would help future devs. Thanks. 

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for this. I would be glad if you still have the link of the OP. The link provided above is broken. Thanks

Comment: @AlvinYanson, is this one:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4k1cd ? (is from this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881107/drag-and-drop-custom-behavior/59882368#59882368)

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo really appreciate it.  Really useful for my requirement.