# Angular Material Drag And Drop (From toolbar to container div)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular with Material Design. Need some help to fix the following problems.

I have a toolbar with some options in it. I need to drag an option into another div but do not want to remove the icon from the original toolbar.

[image]

The code i used is...

```
    <mat-accordion multi>
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title class="listtitle">
                    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" class="mat-icon-title">home
                    </mat-icon>
                    Section 01
                </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-list role="list">
                <mat-list-item cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#reportlayout" role="listitem">
                    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" class="mat-icon-item">list
                    </mat-icon>
                    Option 01
                </mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#reportlayout" role="listitem">
                    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" class="mat-icon-item">list
                    </mat-icon>
                    Option 02
                </mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#reportlayout" role="listitem">
                    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" class="mat-icon-item">list
                    </mat-icon>
                    Option 03
                </mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#reportlayout" role="listitem">
                    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" class="mat-icon-item">list
                    </mat-icon>
                    Option 04
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>

</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile id="reportlayout" colspan="3" style="background-color:cadetblue;">
    <div cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#reportlayout" class="reportrow">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" class="mat-icon-item">list
        </mat-icon>
        Option 01
    </div>
    <div cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#reportlayout" class="reportrow">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" class="mat-icon-item">list
        </mat-icon>
        Option 02
    </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Tried searching the web to get a tutorial.... No luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a resumen between this two SO

1. [Angular CDK Drag Drop Absolutely Position Elements Without
   Jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970847/angular-cdk-drag-drop-absolutely-position-elements-without-jumping/59971728#59971728)
2. [How to use Angular's Drag and Drop module to drag an element onto
   another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685316/how-to-use-angulars-drag-and-drop-module-to-drag-an-element-onto-another/59698494#59698494)

To position your items has properties: x, y, and z-index (futhermore the data you need), e.g.

```
[{label:'Get to work',x:0,y:0,'z-index':0},
```

And your cdk-drag like

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of done">
    <div
      cdkDrag
      class="item-box"
      [style.top.px]="item.y"
      [style.left.px]="item.x"
      [style.z-index]="item['z-index']"
      (cdkDragStarted)="changeZIndex(item)"
      (cdkDragDropped)="changePosition($event, item)"
    >
      {{ item.label }}
      <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="field-placeholder"></div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

To "don't disapear" you create two elements identicals (one can be dragged and another not) and use a variable "onDrag" so you see one or another. See that you use `[style.display]="onDrag ? 'none' : ''"` **not** a `*ngIf`  in the way

```
<div class="wrapper-list">
    <div class="ezample-list"
         [style.display]="onDrag ? 'none' : ''"  cdkDropList>
        <div cdkDrag class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo"
           (cdkDragStarted)="onDrag = true"
           (cdkDragEnded)="onDrag = false"
        </div>
    <div class="example-list"
      [style.display]="!onDrag ? 'none' : ''"  >
    </div>
</div>
```

The "magic" is not use transferArray to "interchange" elements else simply add a new element

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>, isDropZone: boolean = false) {
    //only if we are dragging between elements
    if (event.previousContainer != event.container) {
      //get the data of the element is dragging
      const data = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
      const index = event.container.data.length;
      //we add to the data of the "drop zone"
      event.container.data.push({
        label: data.label,
        x:
          this._pointerPosition.x -
          this.off.x * this.scaleX -
          this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y:
          this._pointerPosition.y -
          this.off.y * this.scaleY -
          this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        'z-index': 0,
      });
      event.item.data.y =
        this._pointerPosition.y -
        this.off.y * this.scaleY -
        this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      event.item.data.x =
        this._pointerPosition.x -
        this.off.x * this.scaleX -
        this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      this.changeZIndex(event.container.data[index]);
    }
    this.posInside = { source: null, x: 0, y: 0 };
  }
```

The .css it's a bit complex, but you can see a working example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ddxk4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

NOTE: in the stackblitz I choose that the elements in the "drag zone" was different that in the "list". It's the reason to a "bit" complex the code because we need get the "scale" like the first example in this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590512/drag-and-drop-image-icons-using-angular/70761246#70761246)

Comment: wow!! Thats exactly what I want.. Thanks a million... You saved my days!!

Comment: @iShah, be carefull, I just updated the code in stackblitz because in the older, when you "drop out" from the drop zone, this add to the "list" -just remove the `this.todo.push(field);` in `changePosition` function