# How to prevent rearrange of children elements upon deleting one child in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have a parent angular component that displays children components with ngFor directive.
Each child acts as an individual window within the parent and their position can be rearranged by CdkDrag.  And I also created a small "X" button on the right top corner to close the child component. And when I hit "x" button to close one child with low index (e.g., 1 or 2 in the stackbliz example below), the other children are rearranged automatically. Is there a way to prevent such rearrangements and stay as is when closing any child window?

**child component**

```
@Input('target') target: string = '';
@Input('index') index: string = '';
@Output() onClose: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

closeModal() {
  const i: number = +this.index;
  this.onClose.emit(i);
}
```

**child template**

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
  {{target}}
  <button class="CloseButton" (click)="closeModal()">X</button>
</div>
```

**child css**

```
.example-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
}

.CloseButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

**parent component**

```
  names: string[] = ['1', '2', '3'];
  modalClosed(id: any) {
    this.names.splice(id, 1);
    console.log(id);
  }
```

**parent template**

```
<div class="ParentMain">
  <child-comp
    *ngFor="let name of names ; index as i"
    (onClose)="modalClosed($event)"
    target="{{name}}"
    index="{{i}}"
  >
  </child-comp>
</div>
```

**parent css**

```
.ParentMain {
  display: flex;
}
```

**Complete stackbliz example**

[Stackbliz example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqf4je?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-comp.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fparent-comp.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fparent-comp.html,src%2Fapp%2Fparent-comp.css,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild-comp.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild-comp.css)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Updated with the code snippet

Comment: @jaeyong am I understanding right that the behaviour you want is for each item to stay in its initial position when one is closed, rather than moving to fill any leftover space?

Comment: @8ytan that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're another approach, that I remember used in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857167/angular-material-drag-and-drop-from-toolbar-to-container-div/70874950#70874950)

If we imagine a cdkDropList with "items" inside we can do some like

```
<div
  cdkDropList
  #doneList="cdkDropList"
  [cdkDropListData]="done"
  class="drag-zone"
  cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
>
  <div
    *ngFor="let item of done;let i=index"
    cdkDrag
    class="item-box"
    [style.top.px]="item.y"
    [style.left.px]="item.x"
    [style.z-index]="item['z-index']"
    (cdkDragStarted)="changeZIndex(item)"
    (cdkDragDropped)="changePosition($event, item)"
  >
    <child-comp
      class="item-box"
      [target]="item.name"
      [index]="i"
      (onClose)="modalClosed($event)"
    >
    </child-comp>
    <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="field-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes a cdkDropList na be different that a list!

```
  names: string[] = ['1', '2', '3'];
  done=this.names.map((x,index)=>({name:x,x:index*100,y:0,"z-index":0}))


  modalClosed(id: any) {
    this.done.splice(id, 1);
    console.log(id);
  }

  @ViewChild('doneList', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) dropZone: ElementRef;

  changeZIndex(item: any) {
    this.done.forEach((x) => (x['z-index'] = x == item ? 1 : 0));
  }
  changePosition(event: CdkDragDrop<any>, field:any) {
    const rectZone = this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rectElement =
      event.item.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    let y = +field.y + event.distance.y;
    let x = +field.x + event.distance.x;
      field.y = y;
      field.x = x;
      this.done = this.done.sort((a, b) =>
        a['z-index'] > b['z-index'] ? 1 : a['z-index'] < b['z-index'] ? -1 : 0
      );
  }
```

And some of .css

```
.drag-zone{
  position:relative;
  flex-grow:1;
  height: 20rem;
  border:1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item-box {
  position:absolute;
}

//see that you die a shadow to de component
//using .cdk-drag-preview + selector of the child component
.cdk-drag-preview child-comp {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
drag-zone
.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqf4je-o7ei1g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent-comp.ts)

Comment: Looks like the rearrange issue is resolved but with this dragStart/dragEnd implementation, the dragging itself is in trouble. The first time drag works fine but in second time, there are glitches and strange movements.

Comment: Check your .css, in the stackblitz looks like work :(. NOTE: I don't check if the page is scrolled

Answer (score 1):

When cdk drag, change the style to the element adding a transform:translate3D. This is the reason that if change the "origin" (you have your elements in a div with flex) the elements arrange in another place.

You can avoid it if, using the event endDrag you give a position absolute and the position top and left. but before, instead makes the "cdkDrag" to a div in a chuild, you can drag the whole element

```
<!--See the template reference variable "wrapper"-->
<div #wrapper style="position:relative;display:flex" >
 
  <!--in cdkDragStarted I pass the component-->
  <child-comp #el cdkDrag (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart(el)" 
                          (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event,i)" 
                          (onClose)="modalClosed($event)"
    *ngFor="let name of names ; index as i"
    target="{{name}}"
    index="{{i}}"
  >
  </child-comp>
</div>
```

In your child component we are going to do accesive the elementRef inject in constructor

```
//In child
constructor(public elementRef:ElementRef){}
```

Well, the dragEnd like

```
  dragEnd(event:CdkDragEnd)
  {
    //get the element:
    const el=event.source.element.nativeElement

    //change the style to position absolute
    el.style.position='absolute'
    el.style.transform=''
    el.style.top=(this.oldPosition.y+event.distance.y)+'px'
    el.style.left=(this.oldPosition.x+event.distance.x)+'px'
  }
```

As you're using a very old version of cdk-drag, you have no the "position" in the event, so we need work a bit in when we startDrag

```
  dragStart(component:any)
  {
    const posWrapper=this.container.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    const pos=component.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    this.oldPosition={x:pos.x-posWrapper.x,y:pos.y-posWrapper.y}
    const el=component.elementRef.nativeElement;
    el.style.top=''
    el.style.left=''
    el.style.position='relative'

  }
```

The last is make the "wrapper" converve the width and heigth when all the elements are dragged

```
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    const posWrapper=this.container.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    this.container.nativeElement.style.width=posWrapper.width+'px'
    this.container.nativeElement.style.height=posWrapper.height+'px'
  }
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqf4je-pcd3tm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent-comp.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild-comp.ts)

Answer (score 0):

It's belonged to how you handle the items position when drag and drop, you need to save item position after onDragEnded event, you can see example  [here:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6swj1n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm afraid your solution isn't really working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the position of each dialogue after the close button is pressed, then there are a number of ways to do it. The simplest is to hide the dialogue when the button is clicked instead of removing them from the template.

Here's an example of doing just that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqf4je-aatkjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-comp.html

In the above, clicking the dialogue causes the item to disappear but the remaining items shouldn't move because the item is in fact still there, it's just been set to opacity: 0.

A slightly more advanced approach that doesn't result in lots of invisible components on the screen would be to use CSS to position the items in specific positions - that way they won't move when one is removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I need to fix the position rather than hiding the element.  The thing with CSS is I already use "cdk-drag" declarative for freely moving the elements and it requires "position: relative" which I can't figure out fixing the position with it.