# Drag and Drop various controls in one container to another in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to have tool box which is having various controls like text box, Date Picker, Drop Down, etc.

This tool box occupies 20% of a screen and remaining 80% is a empty container.

When ever I try drag and drop the controls from tool box to empty container it should brings the copy of a control.

Is it possible in angular Material without using any third party paid bundles?

Comment: take a look to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857167/angular-material-drag-and-drop-from-toolbar-to-container-div/70874950#70874950