# Angular drag-drop icons to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop

I need help with angular drag and drop. It's like I need to drag an icon to a canvas.

I had gone through many examples and [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-drag-3jdk6f) is the example I have reached. when I drag that object the copy of the object should be moved. I had looked at many examples, please anyone help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881107/drag-and-drop-custom-behavior/59882368#59882368 ?

Comment: @Eliseo from your suggestion [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngns5p-hhh?file=src/app/example/example.component.ts) the text is fixed when it is in the box. how to change that property once it is placed it can be again replaced to another position inside the box

Answer (score 1):

our "fields" are object with text,top and left. So, you can create a function

```
changePosition(event:CdkDragEnd<any>,field)
  {
    console.log(field)
    field.top=+field.top.replace('px','')+event.distance.y+'px'
    field.left=+field.left.replace('px','')+event.distance.x+'px'
  }
```

And you call in the .html

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields;" cdkDrag (cdkDragEnded)="changePosition($event,field)"
          style="position:absolute;z-index:10" [style.top]="field.top" [style.left]="field.left">
                    {{field.text}}
            </div>
```

**Updated** the problem, as Ananthakrishna let me know is that you can drag out of the "dop-zone" one element in drop zone

We need use the event `cdkDragDropped`

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields;" cdkDrag 
    (cdkDragDropped)="changePosition($event,field)"
     style="position:absolute;z-index:10" 
     [style.top]="field.top" 
     [style.left]="field.left">
        {{field.text}}
</div>
```

And, in our function changePosition "check" if is droppend inside. I use getBoundingClientRect of the elements relateds:

```
changePosition(event:CdkDragDrop<any>,field)
  {
    
    const rectZone=this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    const rectElement=event.item.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()

    let top=+field.top.replace('px','')+event.distance.y
    let left=+field.left.replace('px','')+event.distance.x
    const out=top<0 || left<0 || 
              (top>(rectZone.height-rectElement.height)) || 
              (left>(rectZone.width-rectElement.width))
    if (!out) //If is inside
    {
       field.top=top+'px'
       field.left=left+'px'
    }
    else{ //we can do nothing
      this.fields=this.fields.filter(x=>x!=field) //or eliminate the object
    }
  }
```

See the forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6xsgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.html)

Comment: but now it can be dragged out of that box, I don't want that. All I need is that It should be in that box, and also can place anywhere inside that box. See in the [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vdmdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts) It is exactly what I needed but once the item is placed inside that box it is locked in its postion. I don't want that, You can understand me right?...

Comment: @Ananthakrishna, sorry the delay, I updated the response and the stackblit. I hope this help you

Comment: NOTE: don't forget `cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"` else when you are moving a droped items all the items become to move randomize

Comment: thank you  I needed this exact one, but even even though I copied the stackbliz code, I'm not getting the exact thing in the result. Is this because of any angular version  mine is angular 9

Comment: can you please join [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218184/angular-drag) chat.

Comment: I am trying to implement same what is done in stackblitz. but after drop item is locked. Please help me to resolve the same

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to achieve your goal with [ng-dnd](https://github.com/ng-dnd/ng-dnd). You can check the [examples](https://ng-dnd.github.io/ng-dnd/examples/index.html#/html5/drop-effects) and have a try.

### Making a DOM element draggable

```html
<div [dragSource]="source">
  drag me
</div>
```

```
constructor(private dnd: DndService) { }

source = this.dnd.dragSource("DRAGME", {
  beginDrag: () => ({ name: 'Jones McFly' }),
  // other DragSourceSpec methods
});
```

### Making a DOM element into a drop target

```html
<div [dropTarget]="target">
  drop on me
</div>
```

```
constructor(private dnd: DndService) { }

target = this.dnd.dropTarget("DRAGME", {
  drop: monitor => {
    console.log('dropped an item:', monitor.getItem()); // => { name: 'Jones McFly' }
  }
})
```