# How to make a drag and drop board in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

is there a way to make a drag and drop board in Angular ? What I want to do is having a column on the right with a list of elements that you could drag in a `div` on the left, and they would get copied in the left box and be able to be moved freely (see image below).

[image: drag-and-drop-board]

So far, i already figured out how to do the list part, but the problem is the board part.
The list is a `div` with the  `cdkDropList` attribute, and the elements in it all have the `cdkDrag` tag to them.

What I wanted to do is that when the user would drag an element from the list to the left board, I would have intercepted the event that is emitted, and copied the element on the board. But the method I created is not triggered when this happens. I tried both `onDragEnd` and `cdkDragEnded`, without success. Maybe am I confused on which element should trigger the event, the box or the item ?

Also, 99% of examples on internet show how to do `cdkDrop` stuff only on lists. I'm almost wondering if Angular's own `DragDropModule` is the right tool for what I want to do.

Here is my item :

```
<div class="rfid-box"
     cdkDrag
     cdkDragEnded="dragEndedProcess()"
     cdkDragBoundary={{boundary_name}}>
    {{object_name}}
</div>
```

And here is my left box (board):

```
<div cdkDrop class="left-box">
        <dragging-box object_name="Télécommande" boundary_name=".left-box"></dragging-box>
</div>
```

As you can see, for now, the "Télécommande" object is manually created, but eventually all elements would be created by dragging from the list on the right.

Comment: Mat, in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812719/angular-drag-drop-icons-to-canvas/62814720#62814720) or in [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916765/drag-and-drop-in-angular-on-complex-board-matrix/59927777#59927777) you has examples about drag in a canvas. You need think not in list else in arrays of object. You "paint" the elements of the arrays what-ever-you-want. You can draw in a fixed position -if the elements of the array has property "x" and "y" you use,e.g. `[style.x]="element.x+'px'"`- or in a simple list

Comment: Thanks for the head start @Eliseo , this is exactly what i needed !