# Allow horizontal positioning in cdkDropList

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk

In my application I have multiple rows, within those rows are "blocks" that can be dragged between rows which works perfectly.

However, In addition to dragging between rows I'd like to be able to freely position them horizontally as well.

[image]

When adding `cdkDropListGroup` and `cdkDroplist`, all elements are automatically left aligned.

For example; I'd like the blue "block" to start where the purple one ends using `cdkDragDrop`.

Comment: Some time ago, someone ask about a "battle-ship". I don't know if can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916765/drag-and-drop-in-angular-on-complex-board-matrix/59927777#59927777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, unfortunately, is not possible using `cdkDropListGroup`. The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) specifically states elements can not be freely dragged around in a `cdkDropList`.

> When outside of a cdkDropList element, draggable elements can be freely moved around the page.

You could set an initial value using  `cdkDragFreeDragPosition` and snap the object to a grid with the `(cdkDragEnded)` event.

Comment: Thank you, I will toy around a bit with `(cdkDragEnded)` to see if I can snap the objects to the grids.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) what you are asking can be done without using the `cdkDropListGroup`.

Instead you should use the `cdkDrag` and `[cdkDragFreeDragPosition]`.

The `[cdkDragFreeDragPosition]` receives and object of the type `{x: number, y: number}`. These will dictate where inside your element the blocks will appear.

Depending on your implementation, you could simply render the elements, one by one, and create a function that returns the `x` and `y` variables for each element. Alternatively, you could create an array that holds all the default placement values.

---

On a side note, it seems that you want the list organization property from the `cdkDropListGroup` and `cdkDropList` directives while simultaneously having the ability to set a custom starting position.

This cannot be done with the current directive. The `cdkDropList` does not accept the `[cdkDragFreeDragPosition]` input so you cannot set the position on the x-Axis yourself.

You would need to develop a custom directive to allow for such to occur.

Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I choose the answer of @Vadiem Janssens since gives me a more direct alternative.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, the CDK drag/drop directive has been updated to include horizontal functionality

`cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"`

**e.g.**

```
<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let timePeriod of timePeriods" cdkDrag>{{timePeriod}}</div>
</div>
```

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#list-orientation