# Why my dragged element into the drop-list is loosing top and left CSS properties, when using Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, css, angular-material, angular10

In last 3 days I was learning Angular Material Drag And Drop, and trying to spike a drag-and-drop of objects/elements into the 10x10 matrix using Angular Material.

After finding [this andswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927777/12603542) and [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-salbpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I was trying to adopt it into my needs and concept. There were some bugs that I had to fix, changed styling, arrays, etc.

[Here is my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vc58aj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I am very close to have it done, but there are two bugs that I can not figure out how to fix them, and I can not find any solution in exampes above:

1. On this one I worked already around 24h. After deploying a ship to the board, and having it deployed, when you are moving the same ship around the board, there is no problem when you move it into the different row and column. But when you move it to the **same column** as it was previously, `app-ship` element (of `ShipComponent`'s selector) looses CSS `left` property. When you move it to the **same row**, it looses CSS `top` property, and is being visually placed at the edge of the matrix, same like with `left` prop. Example for dragging into the same column:
   [image]
   I totally have no idea why it looses these properties.
2. Second bug, that I did not work on yet, but maybe you will have some ideas now, happens when you have already deployed 2 or more ships into the game board, and at first you are shifting one ship, and after this another, instead of another ship will be shiftet the first one, and the secon one will be moved to the upper left corner with missing `left` and `top` CSS properties.

It is very possible, that these 2 issues might be related to each other.

component.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import {
  CdkDragDrop,
  moveItemInArray,
  transferArrayItem,
} from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";
import { ShipComponent } from "./ship.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})

//https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-salbpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
export class AppComponent {
  public list1: Array<ShipComponent>;
  public list2: Array<ShipComponent>;
  public boardP1: number[][];
  public position: any;

  constructor() {
    this.boardP1 = this.getEmptyBoard();
    this.list1 = this.createFleet();
    this.list2 = [];
  }

  @ViewChild("two", { read: ElementRef, static: false }) boardElement: any;
  @ViewChild("ships", { read: ElementRef, static: false }) shipsElement: any;

  onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<Array<ShipComponent>>) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(this.position);
    event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex].top =
      this.position.y -
      this.boardElement.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().y;
    event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex].left =
      this.position.x -
      this.boardElement.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().x;

    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }

    console.log("t: " + event.container.data[event.previousIndex].top);
    console.log("l: " + event.container.data[event.previousIndex].left);
    console.log("s: " + event.container.data[event.previousIndex].size);
    if (this.shipsElement.nativeElement) {
      console.log("top: " + this.shipsElement.nativeElement.style.top);
      console.log("left: " + this.shipsElement.nativeElement.style.left);
    }
  }

  private createFleet(): Array<ShipComponent> {
    return [
      { size: 4, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 3, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 3, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 2, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 2, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 2, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 1, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 1, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 1, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
      { size: 1, rotate: false, top: 0, left: 0 },
    ];
  }

  private getEmptyBoard(): number[][] {
    return Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => Array(10).fill(0));
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="ships">
    <h2>Available ships: {{ this.list1.length }}</h2>
    <div
      class="droplist"
      cdkDropList
      #one="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="list1"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[two]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)"
      cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
    >
      Next:

      <ng-container *ngIf="list1.length > 0">
        <div cdkDrag [style.size]="50 * list1[0].size + 'px'">
          <app-ship [size]="list1[0].size"></app-ship>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-boundary">
  <div
    class="droplist"
    cdkDropList
    #two="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="list2"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[one]"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)"
    cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
  >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let ship of list2">
      <app-ship
        #ships
        [size]="ship.size"
        cdkDrag
        [style.top.px]="ship.top"
        [style.left.px]="ship.left"
      >
      </app-ship>
    </ng-container>
    <div class="board">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of boardP1">
        <div class="cell" *ngFor="let box of row" id="columns">
          <button
            #bt
            mat-button
            class="bt-cell"
            (mouseover)="position = bt.getBoundingClientRect()"
          ></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This mentioned example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-salbpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) works online, but did not work correctly on my local machine, maybe because of Angular 8 versions, and I am using 10+. Also I could not find a way to fix my bugs. I decided to re-build my sample project and get more control on things done by **Material Drag and Drop** in my component.

At the end, in working solution, I decided to get rid of `CdkDragDrop` event, `moveItemInArray`, `transferArrayItem` and do manually operations on arrays and objects. Right now I am using only: `cdkDrag`, `cdkDragStarted`, `cdkDragEnded`, `cdkDragMoved` events.

[Here is version of my solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ec3hkp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fship.component.ts) with fixed mentioned bugs.